# httpcontext.current.server.mappath returning wrong path

Tags: c#, visual-studio, server, path

I have used

"httpcontext.current.server.mappath"

about 2 years ago which never gave me any problem in any deployment till now.

Now I have deployed to a new windows server IIS.

The above statement has been returning, my local machine path.

I could not make out why?

Can anybody throw some light!!!

[image]

Comment: path including the folder names of the visual studio solution in my local machine instead of path on the server.

Comment: There is a dll-library missing on your new IIS https://superuser.com/questions/1163409/msvcp120-dll-and-msvcr120-dll-are-missing

Comment: fubo, Thank you for quick reply. I have attached an image to original post for correct representation of the problem. Hope it adds some more insights. DLL is there. Deployed system is looking for "my LOCAL PATH" and failing.

Comment: The image says _"Error loading msvcr.dll"_

Comment: It is resolved now. My Local Solution's Temp files and logs have been hitting bad on the end deployment. After clearing every one of them and clean deployment resulted to success. I don't know why end deployment is maintaining link to a local temps and logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood your concern and giving better solution as per my knowledge.

Please go to your local machine (`C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp`) delete all the files from that and try to build again.